# Javascript multiple countdown timers on the same page using dates from django models

Tags: javascript, django

this is my first ever post so please let me know if I need to clarify anything thanks.

I don't have any Javascript experience and I'm trying to write a countdown timer that runs through a django model's data and displays a countdown timer based on each individual object date in my database.

My django models work correctly and loops correctly etc.

I place the below script within my django models for loop but the script only pulls the first objects target date and then populates the countdown timer(correctly) for my first django model object's targetdate but it uses the date of only this first model.

My guess is that I need to put the targetdate (the folowing piece of code) :

```
let targetdate  = new Date({{ datemodel.dateinmodel|date:"U" }} * 1000);
```

also in some sort of for loop within javascript itself. I've tried to do this but I really still struggle a lot with javascript at the moment so I don't have any idea.

Do I need to put the target date also in some sort of loop within my javascript script to be able to make it loop through the rest of the object dates in my django model?

Please find the script that I've got so far below :

```
<script>

var clockdiv = document.getElementsByClassName("clockdiv");

let targetdate  = new Date({{ datemodel.dateinmodel|date:"U" }} * 1000);


document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {
  if (event.target.readyState === "complete") {

      var clockdiv = document.getElementsByClassName("clockdiv");


    var countDownDate = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < clockdiv.length; i++ ) {
        
          countDownDate[i] = new Array();
          countDownDate[i]['el'] = clockdiv[i];
          countDownDate[i]['time'] = new Date(targetdate).getTime();
          countDownDate[i]['days'] = 0;
          countDownDate[i]['hours'] = 0;
          countDownDate[i]['seconds'] = 0;
          countDownDate[i]['minutes'] = 0;
      }
    
    
    var countdownfunction = setInterval(function() {
for (var i = 0; i < countDownDate.length; i++) {
              var now = new Date().getTime();
              var distance = countDownDate[i]['time'] - now;
               countDownDate[i]['days'] = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
               countDownDate[i]['hours'] = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
               countDownDate[i]['minutes'] = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
               countDownDate[i]['seconds'] = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
              
               if (distance < 0) {
                  countDownDate[i]['el'].querySelector('.days').innerHTML = 0;
              countDownDate[i]['el'].querySelector('.hours').innerHTML = 0;
              countDownDate[i]['el'].querySelector('.minutes').innerHTML = 0;
              countDownDate[i]['el'].querySelector('.seconds').innerHTML = 0;
               }else{
countDownDate[i]['el'].querySelector('.days').innerHTML = countDownDate[i]['days'];
              countDownDate[i]['el'].querySelector('.hours').innerHTML = countDownDate[i]['hours'];
              countDownDate[i]['el'].querySelector('.minutes').innerHTML = countDownDate[i]['minutes'];
              countDownDate[i]['el'].querySelector('.seconds').innerHTML = countDownDate[i]['seconds'];
}

   }
          }, 1000);
  }
});
</script>
  

<div class="clockdiv" >
  <div>
    Countdown until target date-
    <span class="days"></span>D
    <span class="hours"></span>H
    <span class="minutes"></span>M
    <span class="seconds"></span>S
    
  </div>

</div>
```

Any guidance on how I should approach this will be appreciated many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion.

I was unable to get it to work within the Django loop itself so my solution was to seperate and load each date object seperately within the views file in django and then to just build a counter for each date by itself.

Its probably not the most effective solution but it worked as I only had 11 plus dates to build countdowns for.

In the code example below I would simply update/+1 number for the "countDownDate", "date" and "demo" fields until I created 11 scripts for my 11 items so each item/section has its own countdown script.

Below is the first and second script as an example.

```
<p id="demo"></p>


<script>

            {{
              let countDownDate = new Date({{ date1.dateinmodel|date:"U" }}*1000).getTime();
              // Update the count down every 1 second
              let x = setInterval(function() {
                // Get today's date and time
                let now = new Date().getTime();
                // Find the distance between now and the count down date
                let distance = countDownDate - now;
                // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
                let days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                let hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                let minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                let seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
                // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="T-" + days + "D " + hours + "H "
                + minutes + "M " + seconds + "S ";
                // If the count down is finished, write some text
                if (distance < 0) {
                  clearInterval(x);
                  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "T- 0D 0H 0M 0S"
               ;
                }
              }, 1000);
             }}
            </script>


<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>
        {{
          let countDownDate2 = new Date({{ date2.dateinmodel|date:"U" }}*1000).getTime();
          // Update the count down every 1 second
          let x = setInterval(function() {
            // Get today's date and time
            let now = new Date().getTime();
            // Find the distance between now and the count down date
            let distance = countDownDate2 - now;
            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            let days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            let hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            let minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            let seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            // Display the result in the element with id="demo2"
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML ="T- " + days + "D " + hours + "H "
            + minutes + "M " + seconds + "S ";
            // If the count down is finished, write some text
            if (distance < 0) {
              clearInterval(x);
              document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "T- 0D 0H 0M 0S"
           ;
            }
          }, 1000);
         }}
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer though but I'm facing similar challenge.. I don't know if you've sorted it out.   I tried converting the data to JSON using JSON dump with that the whole params comes out for each of the timers. And I see that in my console.log so next challenge is to be able to pass all to the table through a loop I was thinking although it's not conventional but might work. Creating another table close to the main table to move this timer out of the for loop entirely and work from there with it..

This is the link to a solution that worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/65218112/16174649